# How to insert values of a dataframe to others dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the first dataframe:

```
df1=

Name
a
b
```

and in the other side I have other dataframes (CSV files) that have the same content. Here is two exemple:

```
df3=      df4=
A B C     A B C 
1 2 3     1 2 3
4 5 6     4 5 6
```

I want to add new column to each dataframe and to add each element of the first dataset to the others. Expected output:

```
df3=      df4=
A B C D    A B C D
1 2 3 a    1 2 3 b
4 5 6 a    4 5 6 b
```

**NB**: I read CSV files as pandas so here the multiple dataframe are multiple csv files and I'm inserting new colum to each file and this column contain an element from the first dataframe.df1.

This is my code it add the last element of df1 to all other df like that:

```
df3=      df4=
A B C D    A B C D
1 2 3 b    1 2 3 b
4 5 6 b    4 5 6 b

import csv
import glob
import pandas as pd

list1=[]
df=pd.read_csv('C:/dataframe_1.csv', sep=',')
for elem in df['Name']:
    list1.append(elem)

for elm in list1:
    os.chdir('C:/New')
    extension = 'csv'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
    for file in all_filenames:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
        df1['new_column']=elm
    df1.to_csv(file, index=False, na_rep='NaN')
```

Comment: You might want to clarify that df3 and df4 are the output of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through both `list1` and `all_filenames`. That is where the problem originates. You are overriding each file *multiple* times, keeping only the last value from `list1` (where *multiple* is equal to `len(list1)`).

Drop the outer loop and use `enumerate` to index into the `list1` instead.

```
list1=[]
df=pd.read_csv('C:/dataframe_1.csv', sep=',')
for elem in df['Name']:
    list1.append(elem)

os.chdir('C:/New')
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

for i, file in enumerate(all_filenames):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
    df1['new_column'] = list1[i]
    
df1.to_csv(file, index=False, na_rep='NaN')
```